# How to set Wifi channel for tethering?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I'd like to pick one of less used channels in a relatively Wifi-saturated area, when using tethering (built-in option, mobile hotspot). I never found an option for changing the default channel and only frustrated questions abound over the net bumping around on various fora.

Does anyone here know maybe, how to change the wifi channel for Android phone acting as mobile hotspot?

Rooted Xperia Mini Pro, Android 4.04